# How can I define Object type returned by a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function like this:

```
type f = () => {a: string, b: number};

const func:f = () => {
    return {
        a: "123",
        b: 1,
        c: 123 
    }
}
```

I expect property c is not allowed because it is not defined in function type f. However, there is no warning from Typescript.

After that, I define the function like this:

```
type f = () => {a: string, b: number};

const func:f = (): {a: string, b: number} => {
    return {
        a: "123",
        b: 1,
        c: 123 
    }
}
```

Not the warning exists:

> Type '{ a: string; b: number; c: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; b: number; }'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'c' does not exist in type '{ a: string; b: number; }'

Why is this happening?